# How to iterate up through nested html table column headers using javascript

Tags: html, jquery

I have a table with nested headers of varying lengths, as seen in the example below. I need to be able to crawl up through the headers for  each column to come up with a string of that path but cannot seem to get it to work using jquery. For example In the code below I would need one string that says "Overall>Score", one that says "Company System > Ethnicity> Hispanic or Latino>vs. Company" and so on.

Is there a way to loop through a nested columns headers?
Thanks for any help in advance.
[image]

```
<table id="fakeTableID"  >
  <thead>
    <tr  ><td rowspan="4" >#</td><td  rowspan="1" colspan="1" >Overall </td><td colspan="3"  rowspan="1" style="text-align:center"  >Company System</td></tr>
    <tr  ><td rowspan="3"    colspan="1" > Score</td><td colspan="3"  rowspan="1" style="text-align:center"  >Ethnicity</td></tr>
    <tr  ><td  rowspan="1" colspan="1" >Hispanic or Latino</td><td  rowspan="1" colspan="1" >Non-Hispanic or Latino</td><td  rowspan="1" colspan="1" >Prefer not to answer</td></tr>
    <tr  ><td    rowspan="1" colspan="1"  >vs. Company</td><td    rowspan="1" colspan="1" >vs. Company</td><td    rowspan="1" colspan="1" >vs. Company</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    
    
    
    <tr >
      
      <td >test </td>
      
      <td >2.95</td>
      <td >-</td>
      <td >-</td>
      <td >-</td>
    </tr><tr >
      
      <td >test </td>
      
      <td >3.02</td>
      <td >-</td>
      <td >-</td>
      <td >-</td>
    </tr><tr >
      
      <td >test </td>
      
      <td >3.08</td>
      <td >-</td>
      <td >-</td>
      <td >-</td>
    </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How would it know not to do "Company System > Ethnicity> Score"?

Comment: How is this data getting populated? Is it some kind of data structure like a JSON or array or something?

Comment: Its likely a scrape job